# Lenovo Thinkpad T420, Mini Dock 3 external monitors, udev rules and a dysfucntional script... (Ubuntu 18.04, with the i3 WM)

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, udev

So I'm trying to configure udev rules to automatically configure my DE/WM (Which ever I'm using at the moment (right now it's i3, may have to stick with this for a bit...) to configure my external monitors upon docking (and swtich back to the internal display when I undock.

I found this script and udev rule https://gist.github.com/seanf/e3be5bf745395d50e975

I modified the script to match my configuration and what I wanted to happen with the monitors...

```
#! /bin/sh -e
# Save this file as /etc/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh

# NB: you will need to modify the username and tweak the xrandr
# commands to suit your setup.

# wait for the dock state to change
sleep 1 

username=jgould

#export IFS=$"\n"

14 if [[ "$ACTION" == "add" ]] ; then
DOCKED=1
logger -t DOCKING "Detected condition: docked"
17 elif [[ "$ACTION" == "remove" ]] ; then
DOCKED=0
logger -t DOCKING "Detected condition: un-docked"
#else
#  logger -t DOCKING "Detected condition: unknown"
#  echo Please set env var \$ACTION to 'add' or 'remove'
#  exit 1
fi

case "$DOCKED" in
"0")
#undocked event
switch_to_local :0 ;;
"1")
#docked event
switch_to_external :0 ;;
esac

# invoke from XSetup with NO_KDM_REBOOT otherwise you'll end up in a KDM            reboot loop
NO_KDM_REBOOT=0
for p in $*; do
case "$p" in
"NO_KDM_REBOOT") NO_KDM_REBOOT=1 ;;
"SWITCH_TO_LOCAL") DOCKED=0 ;;
esac
done

44 function switch_to_local {
export DISPLAY=:0
#export XAUTHORITY=$(find /var/run/kdm -name "A${DISPLAY}-*")
#export XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/sflaniga/xauthority
logger -t DOCKING "Switching off HDMI2/3 and switching on LVDS1" 
su $username -c ' /usr/bin/xrandr  --output HDMI-1 --off --output HDMI-2  --off --output HDMI-3 --off --output VGA-1  --off  --output LVDS-1 --auto '
}

function switch_to_external {
export DISPLAY=:0
#export XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/sflaniga/xauthority
#export XAUTHORITY=$(find /var/run/kdm -name "A${DISPLAY}-*")

# The Display port on the docking station is on HDMI2 - let's use it and   turn off local display
logger -t DOCKING "Switching off LVDS1 and switching on HDMI2/3"

su $username -c ' /usr/bin/xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off --output HDMI-1 --off --output HDMI-3 --auto --primary --output HDMI-2 --auto --left-of    HDMI-3 '
}

#case "$DOCKED" in
#  "0")
#    #undocked event
#    switch_to_local :0 ;;
#  "1")
#    #docked event
#    switch_to_external :0 ;;
#esac
```

The script can be tested by passing an Action (add or remove, depending on which way you are testing to /sbin/thinkpad.sh

```
jgould@Ash:~$ ACTION=remove /sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh 
/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh: 14: /sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh: [[: not found
/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh: 17: /sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh: [[: not found
/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh: 44: /sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh: function: not found
```

Thats the result, however syslog provides less useful (to me anyway) information:

> Jun  3 23:52:33 Ash systemd-udevd[4521]: Process '/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh' >failed with exit code 2.
>   Jun  3 23:52:33 Ash systemd-udevd[4527]: Process '/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh' >failed with exit code 2.
>   Jun  3 23:52:33 Ash systemd-udevd[4524]: Process '/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh' >failed with exit code 2.
>   Jun  3 23:52:33 Ash systemd-udevd[4520]: Process '/sbin/thinkpad-dock.sh' >failed with exit code 2.

I have been fooling with this for the last few days and I've read up on udev rules and I'm pretty sure that part is correct, syslog says we're moving the correct direction when we dock and undock.

I'm at a loss on what is actually going on...

Any ideas?

Comment: The first and most obvious thing is that `[[ . . . ]]` is a bash feature - on Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is the dash shell, so you will need to change the shebang to read `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Ok, changing the shebang seems like it will work...  The testing I just did threw no errors I’ll test it more when I get home where my dock is...

Comment: When I got home, I docked the thinkpad and it worked. I’m going to install XFCE on a spare drive and see if it still works.